# Power Automate - Get Outlook Email Distribution Groups

Tags: power-automate

I need assistance with getting all email distribution groups in outlook via Power Automate.

My intention is to send personalized emails to selected Outlook distribution email groups via Power Automate.

[image]

I tried searching for groups however the only groups that i get is from Microsoft 365 and those are not the same as my outlook contacts/groups.

My expectation was to get a list of groups created in outlook so i can select any and make an automation to send personalized emails using power automate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Send an HTTP request V2** action from the **Office 365 Groups** connector to query Microsoft Graph for the distribution lists.

[image: Send an HTTP request V2 action]

Set the URI to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailEnabled eq true and NOT(groupTypes/any(s:s eq 'Unified'))&$count=true`. This tells Microsoft Graph to return all groups that are email enabled and where the group type doesn't contain **Unified**. This should limit the results to distribution lists.

Microsoft Graph considers this type of query to be an [advanced query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries) which requires that the request include the `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` header and the `$count=true` query string.